# Restore Grub - Cannot Find File

Tags: grub2, multiboot

I had Ubuntu and Win 7 on different partitions. And then i formatted partition which containing Win 7 and reinstall Win 7. And then dual boot screen disappeared. I'm following tohuwawohu's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81291/restore-grub-cannot-find-file/81310#81310).

My HDD partition is sda5 which Ubuntu installed.

Now i'm trying to boot my computer, after BIOS loading , i'm getting GRUB command prompt screen ([screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/232/vmwarei.png/sr=1)) directly.

TO solve it, i'm following [this steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.27.27grub.3E.27.27_Prompt_Booting) .

REsult is like this : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error , how I fixed it was like this:
I used Boot repair, a tool to fix grub

Boot into the LiveCD and use the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

and launch Boot repair, choosing the right options from the GUI

Answer (score 2):

I assume those steps relate to `grub`, not `grub2`. With `grub2`, the file structure has changed, so there are no more `stage` file in the `grub` directory. In [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275), under #13, you will find a description how to restore grub2 from a LiveCD. **EDIT2**: It has the following steps (credits [drs305](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=223945)):

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD (Try without installing).
2. From the Desktop, open a terminal - Applications, Accessories, Terminal.
3. Determine your normal system partition - `sudo fdisk -l` (That is a lowercase L).

   If you aren't sure, run `df -Th`. Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.
4. Mount your normal system partition:

   > sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

   - If you aren't sure if you mounted the correct partition, once it's mounted run "`nautilus /mnt`" to inspect the partition. If it is the correct partition, you should see the normal Ubuntu folders such as /bin, /boot, /etc, /home, etc
   - Example: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
   - Note: The partition to mount is normally the partition on which Ubuntu was installed: sda1, sdb5, etc. If you have a separate /boot partition, use the device on which the /boot partition is located. Grub 2 works best when installed in the MBR of the drive to which BIOS boots. Also remember that you mount the partition (including the number) in this step, but you do not include the partition number when you run the "sudo grub-install" command later.
   - Note: GRUB 2 counts the first drive (X) as "0", but the first partition (Y) as "1"
5. **Only** if you have a **separate boot partition**:

   > sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot

   with sdXY being your /boot partition designation.
6. Reinstall GRUB 2:

   > sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX

   Do **NOT** include the partition number.
7. Example:

   > sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

   - **Note**: Substitute the device on which Ubuntu was installed - sda, sdb, etc. Do **NOT** specify a partition number.
8. Unmount the partition *:

   > sudo umount /mnt

   - Note: If you mounted a separate /boot partition, unmount it first:

   > sudo umount /mnt/boot
9. Reboot.
10. After reboot: Update the grub menu using `sudo update-grub`

[Here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7)'s another description. Good luck!

**EDIT1**: Some more information is also available in the [Ubuntu Wiki on `grub2`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2).

Comment: I`m not sure which partition i`ll use : http://pastebin.com/qXEeipCd . Also please look at to last addition of question. thank you.

Comment: AFAIK you don't have to name a certain partition, since `grub2` has to be placed in the MBR of the hard disk. So you will just have to choose the correct hard drive. Your partition list looks as if there's just only on HDD: `/dev/sda`. EDIT: There's only one linux partition `/dev/sda5` so i assume you don't have a special boot partition.

Comment: there is a HDD but there are a few partition on HDD

Comment: There's only one linux partition `/dev/sda5` so i assume you don't have a separate boot partition.

Comment: As i said i can see my ubuntu's partition on file browser. I opened it and then **right click > properties** . I see it's name is `a9115410-9342-47d0-9585-59174e7149db` . And then i execute `df -Th` on terminal. `/dev/sda5` mounted on `/media/a9115410-9342-47d0-9585-59174e7149db` . So, i found my partitions name, it's **sda5**

Comment: Now i'm following this page's (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) instructions for sda5 . But when i restart directly opening GRUB console after BIOS load. There isn't any dual boot screen.

Comment: you may have to refresh the `grub2` menu using the command `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I tried `sudo upgrade-grub` . I'm getting same screen like this after BIOS loading : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/232/vmwarei.png/sr=1 (I found this screenshot from internet)

Comment: Here's some [info how to proceed on the grub prompt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.27.27grub.3E.27.27_Prompt_Booting).

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/grub.png/

Comment: then you will have to check the correct partition number, e.g. using a live cd.

Comment: i'm using live cd . I found sda5 with `fd -Th` command. Also you said, "There's only one linux partition /dev/sda5"

Comment: Yes - but both can't be true, so there's no other way than to re-check the system. If grub tells there's no sda5 partition, you need to check if something has changed or if there's a problem with the partition table.

Comment: really thanks for everything ! Amith KK's answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the below link

[RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)