# Boot problem, keep on asking for the cd

Tags: 11.10, installation

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 from a disk image cd to a clean (no o/s) hard drive but cannot get it to boot from the hard drive although the boot sequence in the bios is for HDD-0, FLOPPY A, CD ROM.  It keep on asking for the cd to boot.  Can someone help please.

Comment: Can you try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/81291/restore-grub-cannot-find-file/81346#81346

(Open with LiveCD)

Comment: From reading your description it almost sounds like you might have simply dragged an iso image of Ubuntu onto a hard drive.. You'll need to describe in more detail what you did. You need to boot the system with an Ubuntu CD and follow the installation directions.

Comment: I wonder if maybe your MBR is frozen.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no data on the hard drive, insert a live cd and reinstall.