# Ubuntu option disappear from grub 11.10 after update on a dual partition

Tags: 11.10, updates, grub2

After today's update Nov. 22, 2011  Ubuntu option disappear from grub 11.10 on my dual partition.

some of fdisk -l:

```
Device Boot      System
/dev/sda1   *    HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        Extended
/dev/sda5        Linux
/dev/sda6        Linux swap / Solaris

Device Boot    ID System
/dev/sdb1   *  c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I also ran this:

```
 grub-probe -t device /boot/grub
```

to see where the grub was got this error:

```
 grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
```

did this too:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

got the same error:
    /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).

I also tried to boot repair Gui but it only shows MBR option and no grub.
when I turn the computer on I get:

```
No such file:
grub rescue>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I also mounted the linux partition:

```
  sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
  mount: /dev/sda5 already mounted or /mnt busy
  mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda5 is already mounted on /mnt
```

and ran the above commands and got the same errors as above.

Also did as tohuwawohu instructed:

```
umount /mnt
sudo fsck -p /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda5: clean,
```

Thanks again. Any Help would be awesome.

Comment: I'm on a live Ubuntu 11.10 I did these commands via the terminal except ofcourse for the grub rescue> error which was on the actual computer which I got after using the Boot repair tool with live Ubuntu because the only option was restore MBR.

Comment: Hmm - maybe a file system issue? Did you run a file system check? Have you tried to proceed [booting "manually"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue_Mode_.28.27.27grub_rescue.3E.27.27.29_Booting) from the rescue prompt?

Comment: To check the file system, **unmount** the partition (`# umount /mnt`) and start the check using `# fsck -v /dev/sda5`. Option `-v` gives verbose output. To automatically repair the file system, add a `-p` or `-a`.

Comment: Another point: If your linux partition is mounted at `/mnt`, its `/boot/grub` directory is available at `/mnt/boot/grub`, not `/boot/grub`. You wrote you ran `grub-probe -t device /boot/grub`.

Comment: @tohuwawohu your right. I get /dev/sda5 but when I do sudo update-grub I still get the same error as above.

Comment: `update-grub` will refresh the grub menu, but it **requires a working grub installation**. So, `update-grub` will work only if you've **managed to boot your original system** (it won't help you if started inside a LiveCD system). Because of that, restoring the MBR may be the best option to get ubuntu back running; after that (and after booting that system), you may restore the multi-boot menu using `update-grub`.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Thank you so very much the answer you posted from the beginning was what resolved it I did: How to proceed in grub rescue mode after reinstalling it again. Then after it booted used the boot repair tool and that made it permanent. Thank you so very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [boot repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Use_Boot-Repair_Graphical_Tool) will help (see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/81346/20661)). You can install it inside a live system using:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Here's some information [how to proceed in grub rescue mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue_Mode_.28.27.27grub_rescue.3E.27.27.29_Booting).

Comment: used the boot repair but that didn't have the option to fix or restore grub only restore MBR