# Boot loading problem after Wubi installation of Ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 7

Tags: grub2, windows, wubi, bootloader

I was new in Ubuntu OS and I was just trying to use wubi windows installer to get a Ubuntu first for hands-on.

I followed exactly the same as the instructions and after reboot win7, there is no `Ubuntu` selection in windows boot manager, with only `Windows 7` showing there evilly -.-

What I've found out was that the `grub` folder inside `Ubuntu` folder ( in my `C:\` drive) was empty, either inside the `ubuntu\disks\grub` or `ubuntu\install\grub`. I thought this might be the reason why I could not load ubuntu during startup.

Cause I've also looked into the `EasyBCD` settings, and `ubuntu entry with Bootloader Path: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` was lying there peacefully, looking perfectly fine. However it was not in boot loader actually.

Is there a way to restore the grub folder with grub2, or is there any way to fix this problem so that I can find the "Ubuntu" selection at windows startup?

Very appreciate your help :)

Henry

Comment: Please notice that wubi is no longer developed and no longer supported, because it does not work with the new versions of Windows that are installed in UEFI mode. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766

Comment: You can try Ubuntu by downloading the ISO, transfer its content into a USB stick, rebooting into the USB stick and installing it. Ubuntu will resize your partition and establish a double boot with Windows automatically

Answer (score 0):

Run a `live Ubuntu CD/USB`.Mount the drive where you installed Ubuntu.Run `terminal` and type `sudo update-grub` and reboot.If you still stuck with grub issue,come back again to live,type this command `sudo install-grub /dev/sda` where `sda` is the drive where Ubuntu lies.Then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81291/restore-grub-cannot-find-file).

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of wubildr (extract from wubi installer with 7zip) and copy to root (C:), together with your wubildr.mbr

You can add an entry with EasyBCD or, if you have grub, you can boot from the grub prompt by entering:

```
search --set=diskroot -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $diskroot
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Then run (once booted):

```
sudo update-grub
```